# How to do bulk instance deletion in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In DRF's [DefaultRouter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter) url router, it requires a `{lookup}` parameter to route DELETE requests to the `destroy` method of a `ModelViewSet` (so, you'd make your request to delete an object instance to the endpoint `{prefix}/{lookup}/`).

This is fine for deleting a single instance, but I'd like to extend that functionality to deleting multiple instances on a single request. Let's say the `lookup` parameter is called `uuid` and the model is called `Product`. Here's an extended version of `destroy`:

```
 def destroy(self, request, uuid=None):
    """
    Overridden method allows either url parameter of single UUID 
    (to delete a single instance), or multiple query parameters `uuids`
    to delete multiple instances.
    """
    if not uuid:
        uuids = request.query_params.get('uuids', None)
        if not uuids:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        if len(uuids) != Product.objects.filter(uuid__in=uuids).count():
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        Product.objects.filter(uuid__in=uuids).delete()
    else:
        instance = self.get_object(uuid)
        if not instance:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        instance.delete()
     return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

So this version takes a DELETE request and multiple `uuids[]` query parameters in the url. Now I just need to route it in `urls.py`:

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter, Route

class BulkDeleteRouter(DefaultRouter):
    """
    a custom URL router for the Product API that correctly routes
    DELETE requests with multiple query parameters.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BulkDeleteRouter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.routes += [
            Route(
                url=r'^{prefix}{trailing_slash}$',
                mapping={'delete': 'destroy'},
                name='{basename}-delete',
                initkwargs={'suffix': 'Delete'}
            ),
        ]

bulk_delete_router = BulkDeleteRouter()
bulk_delete_router.register(r'product', ProductViewSet, base_name='product')
```

This, unfortunately, has killed my url router. It won't resolve GET to the appropriate methods in the viewset, and I don't understand why - isn't my `BulkDeleteRouter` supposed to extend this functionality from the `DefaultRouter`? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Why not to use https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing
with `detail=False` param ?

Comment: Note that using "if not uuid" is bad practice. You want to check whether "if uuid is None"

Answer (score 3):

Forgot to add the router urls to the `urlpatterns`. I must be blind.

```
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^API/', include(bulk_delete_router.urls, namespace='api')),
]
```

Comment: No, it's an actual answer. It is the reason why the urls wouldn't resolve; the `urlpatterns` no longer included the necessary `url()` entries when I changed the router name without updating `urlpatterns`.

Answer (score 3):

Adding an additional `'delete': 'destroy'` to the 'List route' route will perfectly do the job.

```
class CustomRouter(DefaultRouter):
    """
    a custom URL router for the Product API that correctly routes
    DELETE requests with multiple query parameters.
    """
    routes = [
        # List route.
        Route(
            url=r'^{prefix}{trailing_slash}$',
            mapping={
                'get': 'list',
                'post': 'create',
                'delete': 'destroy', # The magic
            },
            name='{basename}-list',
            detail=False,
            initkwargs={'suffix': 'List'}
        ),
        # Dynamically generated list routes. Generated using
        # @action(detail=False) decorator on methods of the viewset.
        DynamicRoute(
            url=r'^{prefix}/{url_path}{trailing_slash}$',
            name='{basename}-{url_name}',
            detail=False,
            initkwargs={}
        ),
        # Detail route.
        Route(
            url=r'^{prefix}/{lookup}{trailing_slash}$',
            mapping={
                'get': 'retrieve',
                'put': 'update',
                'patch': 'partial_update',
                'delete': 'destroy'
            },
            name='{basename}-detail',
            detail=True,
            initkwargs={'suffix': 'Instance'}
        ),
        # Dynamically generated detail routes. Generated using
        # @action(detail=True) decorator on methods of the viewset.
        DynamicRoute(
            url=r'^{prefix}/{lookup}/{url_path}{trailing_slash}$',
            name='{basename}-{url_name}',
            detail=True,
            initkwargs={}
        ),
    ]
```

Then use the router like this:

```
custom_router = CustomRouter()
custom_router.register(r'your-endpoint', YourViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(custom_router.urls)),
]
```

The viewset:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.db.models import QuerySet
class MachineSegmentAnnotationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        qs: QuerySet = self.get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        qs.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Hope this helps.